# Installation of IDAS to Use with ORION CB

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, iot

I have an Orion CB working on a virtual machine just fine.

Now i have a gateaway that communicates in mqtt. So i want to use IDAS as an iot Agent to make the link between my GW and Orion CB.

My question is how do i install IDAS?

I have this : https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus/

It really is not clear at all what are the spteps to take in order to install and use it. Can any one explain?

Or is there any kind of Virtual machine with IDAS already installed on it, like for the orion CB?

Thanks

Comment: NOTHING ? After so many time no awnser....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I ended up asking the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999266/rpms-for-idas-iotagents-ge-from-fiware).
The easiest way to install IDAS on a CentOS machine is through its RPM's available in it's calogue page. 
As of now I'm having other issues with such installation, but maybe you won't have them.
I hope this helps even though it comes so late.